# Can I use APCu in Lithium of the PHP Framework with no configuration, or should I change the code?

Tags: php, lithium

When I setup a lithium project (below process) and start PHP web server, I get an information of Apc disable (Apc ✗) on the framework's welcome page.

But I run `sed -ir "s/'apc'/'apcu'/" libraries/lithium/storage/cache/adapter/Apc.php`, then I get Apc enabled (Apc ✓).

This code change is correctly? or not?

## Environment

- Fedora 26 (x86_64)
- PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul  6 2017 12:10:54) ( NTS )
- php-pecl-apcu 5.1.8
- Composer version 1.4.2 2017-05-17 08:17:52

Detail:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep php
php-pdo-7.1.7-1.fc26.x86_64
php-pecl-apcu-devel-5.1.8-2.fc26.x86_64
php-7.1.7-1.fc26.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-7.1.7-1.fc26.x86_64
php-json-7.1.7-1.fc26.x86_64
php-devel-7.1.7-1.fc26.x86_64
php-cli-7.1.7-1.fc26.x86_64
php-pecl-apcu-5.1.8-2.fc26.x86_64
php-common-7.1.7-1.fc26.x86_64
```

## How to setup of the Lithium, and access the framework's welcome page:

```
$ composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist unionofrad/framework app
Installing unionofrad/framework (v1.1.1)
  - Installing unionofrad/framework (v1.1.1): Loading from cache
Created project in app
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing composer/installers (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing unionofrad/lithium (v1.1.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
$ cd app/
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t app/webroot index.php
```

## Setting diff

.orig file is the backup.

- /etc/php.ini:

  ```
  $ diff /etc/php.ini.orig /etc/php.ini
  460c460,461
  < error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
  ---
  > ;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
  > error_reporting = E_ALL
  ```
- /etc/php.d/40-apcu.ini:

  ```
  $ diff /etc/php.d/40-apcu.ini.orig /etc/php.d/40-apcu.ini
  9a10
  > apc.enable_cli=1
  ```

## Cases

### with a `-c /etc/php.ini` parameter

Run with the parameter, but it no effect,:

```
$ php -c /etc/php.ini -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t app/webroot index.php
```

shows Apc disable (Apc ✗).

Comment: Perhaps you need to start the PHP built-in web server with a `-c /etc/php.ini` parameter?

Comment: @blubear Thanks, but it couldn't make no sense... I tried to run with the case of 'with a `-c /etc/php.ini` parameter'. (See updated question's Cases section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `php-pecl-apcu-bc` package by dnf makes adapting to Apc ✓. But `php-pecl-apcu-bc` is "APCu Backwards Compatibility Module"... oh.

Before installed:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
apcu
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

After installed:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
apcu
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```